# Need functions that both allocates memory for a string's creation, and inputs that string into an array of character pointers also allocated

Tags: c, function

Here back again with another question!

```
#include <stdio.h>      // For standard input-output
#include <stdlib.h>     // For malloc
#include <string.h>     // For strcmp
#include <ctype.h>      // For isdigit
#define WordSize 20 // Macro defining maximum word size

char * input(void);

void addWord(char*,char**,int);

int main(void){
    // Define variables
    int Num_Words;
    // Prompt user for number of words, make sure to verify input 
    printf("How many words do you wish to have: ?");
    while(scanf("%d", &Num_Words) !=1)
        {
            printf("Invalid entry, please try again!");
        }
    // Allocate memory for words (char **)!
    char ** NumWords = malloc(Num_Words * sizeof(int));

    // Get user input for each word, add pointer for each word to words 


    char * ptr = malloc(WordSize * sizeof(char));
    addWord(ptr, NumWords, Num_Words);

    return 0;
}



char * input()
{
    char string;
    while(scanf("%s", &string) != 1)
        {
            printf("Please input valid string! \n");
            while(getchar() != '\n' ){}
        }

    char * array = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * string);
    *array = string;

    return array;
}

void addWord(char* word, char** words, int NumofWords)
{
    //TO-DO: Implement addWord

    for (int i = 0; i < NumofWords; i++)
        {
            printf("Enter word %d: \n ", i + 1);
            word = input();
            *words[i] = *word;
        }
    return;
}
```

Excuse the quotes, because some of them are mine and some are provided form the skeleton code to try and give direction. Again fairly new to coding and this is a kicker of a question, but the issue I am having at present is through the function `inputWord` and `addWord` as the iteration does not work and I get kicked out of the program at word 3. What I am supposed to do is ask the user for the number of words they wish to input (ditto), then from their do a dynamic allocation for the total number of words (ditto?) and then for each word cast a pointer to the user defined string , iterating to to fill the number of words defined earlier by the user. I don't really know what the problem/issue is? It compiles fine, but compiling doesn't mean functionality whatsoever. Any thoughts or areas I should look at.

Comment: I still need to go through and do a free memory function for the list of pointers and other function but I'll hash those issues out myself and look at what you brilliant minds discussed here so far. I'm just stumped on why I keep getting booted out during the itteration

Comment: `char string;` is a *single* character, but is followed by `while(scanf("%s", &string) != 1)` which wants an array. Later in the function `*array = string;` is quite wrong, also `sizeof(char) * string` as the argument for `malloc`. The whole function `inputWord()` is off.

Comment: OT: regarding: `while(scanf("%s", &string) != 1)`   when using the 'input format conversion' specifiers `%s` and/or `%[...]`  always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This avoids any possibility of a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior

Comment: @SeanBright sorry about that! Still new to the whole process my bad and got super sidetracked yesterday, I'll upload the rest of the cde

Comment: @TobySpeight Phew! There we go! Hopefully that fits the minimum requirements, been a crazy day today hehe, but actually having things fleshed out in a simpler fashion takes the edge off too

Comment: I understand where of my issues were! When demonstrating the pointer-pointers, when assgining the memory, the sizeof() was incorrect and was allocating to the size of the integer versus the size of char *

Answer (score 0):

the question:

Need functions that both allocates memory for a string's creation, and inputs that string into an array of character pointers also allocated

first, allocate the array of pointer:

```
char *arrayOfPointers = calloc( 100, sizeof( char* ) );
```

then use: getline()` to input the string into allocated memory into the array of pointers.

Comment: aaaah, getline! Completely forgot about that! Yeah that would make more sense, I updated my code as well because I realized that I was held off on a lot of code needed for people to actually try and compile my work, BUT I think that would be the missing bit